# Microsoft openid login flow picture access

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-account

I have an MVC app that uses the preview 2.0 endpoint.  I'm a little disappointed that the profile image is not a default object.  Having said that, I'm having issues trying to figure out how to properly get the profile picture using the endpoint.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What flow are you referring to? OIDC, OAuth? Normally graph is used to obtain additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenId connect for Azure AD doesn’t support to get the users’ profile picture at present as you mentioned.

However, if you were only working on Azure AD accounts, we can use the Microsoft Graph to get the users profile picture separately. To call this REST, we can grant the User.Read scope to the app and here is the code for your reference:

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // The `Authority` represents the v2.0 endpoint - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0
                // The `Scope` describes the initial permissions that your app will need.  See https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-scopes/                    
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, "common", "/v2.0"),
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,                    
                Scope = "openid email profile offline_access Mail.Read User.Read",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    // In a real application you would use IssuerValidator for additional checks, like making sure the user's organization has signed up for your app.
                    //     IssuerValidator = (issuer, token, tvp) =>
                    //     {
                    //        //if(MyCustomTenantValidation(issuer)) 
                    //        return issuer;
                    //        //else
                    //        //    throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("Invalid issuer");
                    //    },
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                        ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(clientId, redirectUri,
                           new ClientCredential(appKey), 
                           new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, context.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase));
                        string[] scopes = { "Mail.Read User.Read" };
                        try
                        {
                            AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(scopes, code);
                        }
                        catch (Exception eee)
                        {

                        }
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = (notification) =>
                    {
                        notification.HandleResponse();
                        notification.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Then we can get the profile picture of Azure AD user like request below:

```
Get: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
authorization: bearer {token}
```

And based on the test, the Microsoft Graph doesn’t support to get the profile picture for Microsoft Account at present. You may submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/), if you want it also support the Microsoft Account.